# How to iterate over matrix and find matching value

Tags: python

```
def is_win(self, player):
    for x,y,z in [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6],
    ]:

    if x == player and y == player and z == player:
         return True
```

I am trying to form a win condition on Tic Tac toe.  But this will not match. I have a update_board function that checks if is_win after updating a players move.

Comment: Your question is remarkably opaque.

Comment: Hint: when you run this code, what do you expect to be the value of `x` the first time through the loop? Of `y`? Of `z`? Of `player`? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to think about the code logically. (Hint 2: I notice that your title says "How to iterate over matrix". What part of this code has anything to do with a matrix, according to your intent? Is there a variable in the code that is supposed to hold the matrix? Which one?)

Comment: so is it not returning expected value?

Comment: `x`,`y` & `z` hold the numbers from each row. I don't know what `player` is, but basically you check if `0 == 1 == 2` for the first row, `3 == 4 == 5` for the second etc...

Answer (score 0):

You should set your player to contain a set of positions. Then, you check if any row in your matrix is in the player's positions.

```
# assuming player.positions is a set()
def is_win(self,player):
    win_matrix = [set([0, 1, 2]),set([3, 4, 5]),set([6, 7, 8]),set([0, 3, 6]),\
                 set([1, 4, 7]),set([2, 5, 8]),set([0, 4, 8]),set([2, 4, 6])]
    for w in win_matrix:
        if(w.issubset(player.positions)):
            return True
    return False
```